# Not able to set default value for dropdown list field, which is filled with category keywords

Tags: 2011, cme, taxonomy

I need to bind a dropdown list field filled with list of keywords under a category.
For this, I did as like below:

1. Created a Category
2. Created a list of keywords under the above category
3. Added a new field of type dropdown list in my schema and set values from the category and then selected one keyword as default value.

But the issue is when I try to create a new component, the dropdown field is not pre-selected with any given default value (keyword).

FYI I made sure that cache is refreshed.

Anybody have any idea?

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probable cause would be the Cache - you might have cleared your browser cache but I hope you have not cleared the Server Cache and even the JVM cache on CM server.

To ensure that it is a cache issue restart SDL Tridion Content Manager DCOM+ application and to be further sure, re-start the SDL Tridion Content Manager IIS App Pool on the CM server along with your browser cache.

Once done successfully, check again.

Comment: Yes it is Purely cache issue, it is working now with recycle the App pool besides COM+.

Comment: @KoteswaraRaoAnkalla if this suggestion solved your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad that it works